# How to convert Python 'None' type to 'NULL' type

Tags: python-2.7, vertica

How to convert Python 'None' type to 'NULL' type? I am querying a Vertica DB using python-vertica module, and writing the result set into a CSV file where Python CSV module inserts NULL as None. So when I am importing this CSV file into a Vetica DB, I am getting empty string as ' ' where in I want it to be NULL. I am guessing the issue here is because of Python None type. How can I resolve this?

Here is the code to export data into CSV:

```
def get_data(table, startDate, endDate, config):
  connFrom = vertica_connect_from(config)
  cursor = connFrom.cursor()

  if startDate == endDate:
      command = "select * from dev.{} where report_date='{}'".format(table,startDate)
  else:
      command = "select * from dev.{} where report_date between '{}' and '{}'".format(table, startDate, endDate)

  cursor.execute(command)
  rows = cursor.fetchall()

  with open(filePath, 'w') as csvfile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="|")
      for row in rows:
          for index, item in enumerate(row):
              if (item == 0.0):
                  row[index] = 0
          writer.writerow(row)
      logger.info('Data has been copied and written to CSV file at %s', filePath)

  connFrom.close()
```

And here is the way I am importing it:

```
def load_data(table, config):
  connTo = vertica_connect_to(config)
  cur = connTo.cursor()

  importCommand = "copy qa.{} from stdin null as '' rejected data '{}' exceptions '{}'".format(table,rejectedLog, exceptionLog)
  with open(filePath, 'r') as fil:
      try:
          cur.copy(importCommand, fil)
      except Exception as e:
          logger.error('%s', e)
      logger.info('Data has been copied, check rejected/exception files at /tmp on the destination host for any errors')

  connTo.close()
```

Comment: it kind of depends on how you are doing it I guess.  Can you update with some sample code?

Comment: have added sample code, could you please check it you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue here is that you want to use NULL as a token, simply add a replacement like you have for 0.0.

```
if not item: 
    row[index] = 'NULL'
```

Then change your copy to accommodate.

```
null as 'NULL'
```